# install4j: Jar not getting packed

Tags: install4j

I'm getting below error while packing one of my service jar

install4j: compilation failed. Reason: java.io.IOException: org/springframework/asm/ClassAdapter.visit(IILLL[L) contains a bytecode 00013: invokeinterface InterfaceMethodref:19 Con:1792 with an unsupported constant reference; please use the pass-file option on this class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid the error, you can add an empty file `<jar name>.jar.nopack` in the same directory as the JAR file that contains this class, the JAR file will be excluded from Pack200 compression.